# LPTHW ex51 so Python thinks bin/ is a directory?

Tags: python

From Learn Python the Hard Way ex51: "...now create an empty `bin/__init__.py` file so Python thinks bin/ is a directory."

As far as I can tell Python does think bin is a directory with or WITHOUT the `__init__.py` file, as shown by:

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: directory = '/Users/username/Envs/env1'

In [3]: os.walk(directory).next()
Out[3]: 
('/Users/mikekilmer/Envs/env1',
 ['bin',
  'docs',
  'include',
  'lib',
  'man',
  'moved',
  'share',
  'templates',
  'temple',
  'tests'],
 ['.DS_Store',
  '.Python',
  'cast.py',
  'cast.pyc',
  'collector.py',
  'collector.pyc',
  'lexicon copy.py',
  'lexicon.py',
  'lexicon.pyc',
  'scenes.py',
  'scenes.pyc'])
```

So what does "so Python thinks bin/ is a directory." mean, please?

Answer (score 3):

You're right, that's a somewhat misleading turn of phrase. What it actually means is that Python will consider `bin` to be **a Python package**, which may contain modules and so on.

With an `__init__.py` file in there, Python will allow you to `import bin`, which you cannot do in the case of a normal, empty directory. This is how Python's packages are "declared": a directory with an `__init__.py` file is considered to be a package (and the contents of that file may be loaded as a module, e.g. `import bin` will import the contents of `bin/__init__.py`). Take a look at the [Packages section of the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for a more thorough description.

Comment: Cool. Thank you. So maybe it would have been more appropriate to say "so Python will treat the directories as containing packages.", right?

Comment: @MikeiLL That's the terminology the docs use, so I'd say it's probably the most apt wording available!

Answer (score 2):

It will allow you to import files from that directory:

#### Without bin/__init__.py

```
[11:49am][wlynch@watermelon example] python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bin
```

#### With bin/__init__.py

```
[11:49am][wlynch@watermelon example] touch bin/__init__.py
[11:49am][wlynch@watermelon example] python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bin
>>> bin
<module 'bin' from 'bin/__init__.py'>
```